# assigning elements to vector in cpp

Tags: c++, vector

I want to copy a vector of size `n` into a vector of size `2*n` that is exactly two continuous copies of vector `a` to `temp`.

I am doing like this:

```
vector<int> temp;
temp.insert(a.begin(), a.begin(), a.end());
temp.insert(a.begin() + n, a.begin(), a.end());
```

But it is throwing exception.

Here is my [whole code](https://ideone.com/tBM8eN).

I have tried also declaring size also `vector<int> temp(2*n)` But it still giving me error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of `insert` should be an iterator into the vector on which the function is called. That is, `temp.begin()`, not `a.begin()`

Comment: Inserting at `temp.end()` would make more sense: `temp.insert(temp.end(), a.begin(), a.end());`

Comment: that particular form of `insert` method is full of possible UBs.